# Where all types for http headers gone in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Previously, in WebApi (on .NET 4.x) we could work with headers of both the request and the response via typed interfaces (see `HttpRequestMessage.Headers`/`HttpResponseMessage.Headers`).
Now, in ASP.NET 5 we have `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` with Headers property of type `IHeaderDictionary`. But it's just an untyped Dictionary.

Below I put an example with typed accessing could return a fine-tuned http-response. It's needed to create a `HttpResponseMessage` and fill its Headers collection (which was typed btw).

```cs
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StringContent(manifestContent);
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/cache-manifest");
response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue {NoCache = true, Public = true};
response.Headers.ETag = new EntityTagHeaderValue("\"" + etag + "\"");
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you add the using statement for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http`, there are extension methods on the `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` to `GetTypedHeaders`, which should give you the type safety that you want.

In the example, I also added the using statement for `Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers`, just to clean it up.

```
var headers = Response.GetTypedHeaders();
headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/cache-manifest");
headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue { NoCache = true, Public = true };
headers.ETag = new EntityTagHeaderValue("\"" + etag + "\"");
```

Source: [aspnet/HttpAbstractions on Github](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/b77e9d2d9ccdf78e4cd0941af53aff08931b8374/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions/HeaderDictionaryTypeExtensions.cs)

Comment: What about HttpContextBase?

Answer (score 1):

In Asp.net 5 the headers collection is now a single class i.e. `HeaderDictionary`  that can be used for both request and response headers. This will act as a key value based store for headers. The good reason I can see is because of Owin support. One store can be used utilized across various Owin supported middleware e.g. WebApi, SignalR which provides you extensibility for adding more information in Header collection.