# How to read header data from a web API response in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am calling the web API methods from my client project and returning the value from response header to client:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("login")]
public IActionResult Login(Users user)
{
    string s = _repository.Users.ValidateUser(user);
    if (s == "success")
    {
        Users u = _repository.Users.FindByUserName(user.UserName);
        int pid = u.PersonId;
        string role = "";
        if (u != null)
        {

            role = _repository.RoleManager.GetRole(u.Id);
        }
        Response.Headers.Add("Role", role);
        return Ok(pid.ToString());
    }

}
```

And I tried the code below for getting header value in the client application:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login(Users user)
{    
    string pid = "";
    HttpClient client = service.GetService();
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/mymethod", user).Result;
    Task<string> tokenResult = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
    pid = tokenResult.Result.ToString();
       
    var headers = response.Headers;
    string role = "";
    if (headers.TryGetValues("Role", out IEnumerable<string> headerValues))
        {
            role = headerValues.ToString();
        }

    return RedirectToAction("Profile");
}
```

But it returns `System.String[]` .

Please show me the right way for fetching data from the response header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract custom header value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794749/how-to-extract-custom-header-value)

Comment: Thanks for reply...it shows reading data from request but I want to read data from response header

Comment: Can you add the code of the getRole-method? I think it’s the source of confusion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution:

```cs
var headers = response.Headers;
string role = "";
if (headers.TryGetValues("Role", out IEnumerable<string> headerValues))
{
    role = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Don't forget to add a reference to `System.Linq`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `StringValues`:

```
var headers = response.Headers;
string role = "";
if (headers.TryGetValues("Role", out Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues headerValues))
{
    role = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: I don't know why in my code there is no `headers.TryGetValues` but `headers.TryGetValue` with no 's'