# Obtain strongly typed header class in ASP.NET Core

Tags: http-headers, asp.net-core, asp.net-controls

How do you obtain a strongly typed header class from the namespace `System.Net.Http.Headers` from an ASP.NET Core controller? In a controller derived from `Controller`, `Request.Headers` is available, but it just returns `IHeaderDictionary`. There is also an extension method `HeaderDictionaryTypeExtensions.GetTypedHeaders`, but it returns `RequestHeaders`, which has only certain headers. The class `HttpRequestHeaders` has the most comprehensive list of headers, but it's not clear how to access it.

For example, how would you get a `AuthenticationHeaderValue`? One option is `AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(Request.Headers["Authorization"])`, but that requires hard coding the header name. Perhaps there is a non-hard-coded way to get to `HttpRequestHeaders.Authorization`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where all types for http headers gone in ASP.NET 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706719/where-all-types-for-http-headers-gone-in-asp-net-5)

Comment: @Tseng That other question has an accepted answer based on the `RequestHeaders`, which is useful for some headers, but not others. This question focuses on how to get the more comprehensive `HttpRequestHeaders` available in ASP.NET Core 1.0.

Comment: I posted this question as an issue on the [GitHub project](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5680).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `AuthenticationHeaderValue` to parse the header string into an object with `Scheme` and `Parameter` properties.

```cs
var auth = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization]);

if (auth.Scheme != expectedScheme || !MyVerifyAuthParamteter(auth.Parameter)) ...
```